# Iterating over ArrayCollection while adding and removing items

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, arraycollection

I want to iterate over an ArrayCollection in Flex while there can be items added and removed.

Since i didn't find a way to use a "classic" Iterator like in Java, which would do the job. I tried the Cursor. But it doesn't really work the way i want it to be ;) So how do I do it nicely ?

```
    var cursor:IViewCursor = workingStack.createCursor();

    while (!cursor.afterLast)
    {
        // Search
                    deepFirstSearchModified(cursor.current.node,nodeB,cursor.current.way);
        // Delete Node
        cursor.remove();
        // Next Node
        cursor.moveNext();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think better to use New Collection/Array for opertations as

```
private function parseSelectedItem(value:IListViewCollection):IListViewCollection{
 var result:Array = new Array();
    for each(var item:Object in value)
    {
        //result.push();
        //result.pop();
    }
    return new ArrayCollection(result) ;
}
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: that will definitly do the job... but i like more the iterator idea which does what i want in a "blackbox"

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following:

```
for (var i:int = myArrayCollection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   myArrayCollection.removeItemAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for your problem:

http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/actionscript-3-apis/

Have a look at the CollectionIterator class.

Cheers

Comment: looks nice but i am not quiet shure if i want to use 3rd party things ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ActionLinq](http://actionlinq.org).  It implements the .Net Linq2Objects pattern, including `IEnumerable`.  Of course, you need to be careful, because you are modifying the items you are iterating over...

```
var workingStack:ArrayCollection = getData();
var iterator:IEnumerable = Enumerable.from(workingStack);

for each(var item:String in iterator) {
  doSomethingTo(workingStack);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In flex (or actionscript) any change that you do, is visible instantly. So you can do what you want in a for:

```
    for (var i : Number = myArrayCollection.length; i > 0; i--) {
       myArrayCollection.removeItemAt(i - 1);
    }
```

I think that should work fine.

Comment: ok that would be nice, because in Java it would throw an exception. have to try it

Comment: removeElement is not a method of an arrayCollection

Comment: @Dukeatcoding, it will indeed throw an exception due to the fact that you will try to delete elements that are not longer at a certain index

Comment: @Duke: working with flex you will see that it doesn't have concurrency  approach for developer. You won't have multithreading problems in flex!

Comment: you have to use removeItemAt instead of removeElement. i will try out the for each in a few minutes, just have to finish something

Comment: @Dennis: You're right. @Duke : now I think it should work. If it doesn't, you should try in same manner, just changing the myArrayCollection.length to your variable

Comment: @All, the reason why it doesn't work this way is described here:
http://form-function.blogspot.com/2008/03/removing-items-from-array-collection.html

Comment: You have to iterate backwards or you end up skipping elements.  If you remove the current element, then increase the counter, you end up skipping the next element